# remove space above the hr tag

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space above hr tag.now I get some unwanted space.I want to remove it.I want to start hr line where I marked in green.Please see my above edited question.This is my whole body section.

[image]

Css

```
 hr {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 660px;
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
 }
 .sidemenu {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 }
.content {
 position:relative;
 }
.side{
width: 24%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

html

```
  <div class="outer">
            <div class="log">
            <h1>Profile</h1>
                   <form method="post" class="lout" > <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button></form>

            </div> <!--End of log div -->
            <div class="rest">
              <div class="side">
               <div class="sidemenu">
                    <div class="1 menu">
                      <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                    </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                    <div class="2 menu">
                      <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                    </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                    <div class="3 menu">
                      <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                    </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                    <div class="menu 4">
                    <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                    </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
               </div> <!--End of side menu -->
               </div>  <!--End of side div -->
               <hr>
                <!--  <div class="heading" >
                     <h1>Profile</h1>
                  </div>    End of heading div -->
               <div class="content">

      </div> 

               </div> <!--End of content -->
            </div> <!--End of rest div -->
      </div> <!--End of outer div-->
```

Comment: could you provide the html / rendered markup for this?

Comment: could you include the css for those divs as well (so that i can reproduce)

Comment: dear @user3386779, u haven't provided with complete code

Comment: guys, do u see any problem in jsfiddler, as he is asking...? i think it's fine. but other CSS classes might be making trouble

Comment: Do you have CSS reset? once I gave margin and padding to 0; I didnt find any space in between.. https://jsfiddle.net/otjwj5uw/

Comment: hard-coding height of 660px? Why?

Comment: I try to avoid `hr` tags. You probably can achieve the result you are after by adding a `top-border` to `.content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove property `margin-top` i.e. `margin-top: 150px;` 
from your class sidemenu :
Use the class mentioned below :

```
.sidemenu {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

To align content to center, add below CSS class to `outer`

```
.outer{
    margin-left:50%;
    width:100%;
}
```

And you will see the desired output.

Comment: ya Itd aligned in left top

Comment: hey, @user3386779, i have edited my answer try it out. is this worked?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed your HTML structure and CSS are as JS below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidemenu">
       left
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
       right
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/uuk8x3jm/3/)**

As you can see with the different background color.  
The padding of the outer wrapper is giving you spacing above the hr tag.

Removed the padding top/padding bottom for the outer wrapper use the padding within the sidemenu and content. As I use in JS below:

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/uuk8x3jm/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Give overflow hidden for outer wrapper